# Why terraform is trying to recreate infrastructures which is already provision?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

When I run the infrastructure creation with jenkins plan for the first time, which is create all the infrastructure such as EC2, EBS, RDS and EFS. I'm maintaining my tf state file in s3 and dynamoDB.
as below.

```
terraform init -plugin-dir=$tf_plugin_dir \
                        -backend-config="bucket=${s3_bucket}" \
                        -backend-config="key=$Purpose/${deploy_env}/tfstate" \
                        -backend-config="region=${aws_region}" \
                        -backend-config="dynamodb_table=${dynamodb_table}" \
```

But when I rerun the plan, As I know it should not be change if there is not to change, But notice it is changing Infrastructure as below.

```
terraform plan -var-file="../../../../configurations/${account_prop_path}/surv.tfvars" -var RelVersion="${RelVersion}" -var Purpose="${Purpose}" -var ami_id="${ami_id}" -var ora_rds_snap_id="${ora_rds_snap_id}"
```

[image]

Also get below error.

> Error: error updating EFS File System "fs-065db0f6": BadRequest: The
> file system won't be updated. The requested throughput mode or
> provisioned throughput value are the same as the current mode and
> value. {   RespMetadata: {
> StatusCode: 400,
> RequestID: "b57a53bb-5a65-4bdc-b748-b441c7ad3d19"   },   ErrorCode: "BadRequest",   Message_: "The file system won't be
> updated. The requested throughput mode or provisioned throughput value
> are the same as the current mode and value." }

Terraform Plan output as below

```
# module.efs-cluster.aws_efs_file_system.efs will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs" {
        arn                             = "arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:eu-west-2:946581213364:file-system/fs-065db0f6"
        creation_token                  = "terraform-20210519172018074600000001"
        dns_name                        = "fs-065db0f6.efs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"
        encrypted                       = true
        id                              = "fs-065db0f6"
        kms_key_id                      = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:946581213364:key/15dc10ff-885a-4217-ad60-05ef9682d34d"
        performance_mode                = "generalPurpose"
      ~ provisioned_throughput_in_mibps = 0 -> 350
        tags                            = {
            "AWSResoureceType"   = "EFS"
            "Account"            = "MITSURV"
            "ApplicationID"      = "APP-00682"
            "ApplicationName"    = "MITCAPMARKET"
            "Automation"         = "PLACEHOLDER"
            "BusinessEntitiy"    = "MIT"
            "CostCentre"         = "CC55219"
            "DBVersion"          = "N/A"
            "DataClassification" = "3"
            "Division"           = "DEVOPS"
            "Environment"        = "NONPROD"
            "Name"               = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-EFS"
            "OSVersion"          = "N/A"
            "Project"            = "SURV"
            "ProjectCode"        = "25127-100"
            "Purpose"            = "QA1"
            "RelVersion"         = "N/A"
            "ResourceName"       = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-EFS"
            "VersionNumber"      = "N/A"
            "Workload"           = "TEST"
        }
        throughput_mode                 = "bursting"
    }

# module.mn-ec2.aws_instance.this[0] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_instance" "this" {
        ami                          = "ami-0e6de0d71c64a2b5b"
      ~ arn                          = "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-2:946581213364:instance/i-0dbe05f55f05d9a4c" -> (known after apply)
      ~ associate_public_ip_address  = false -> (known after apply)
      ~ availability_zone            = "eu-west-2a" -> (known after apply)
      ~ cpu_core_count               = 8 -> (known after apply)
      ~ cpu_threads_per_core         = 2 -> (known after apply)
        disable_api_termination      = false
        ebs_optimized                = false
        get_password_data            = false
      - hibernation                  = false -> null
      + host_id                      = (known after apply)
        iam_instance_profile         = "mit-surv-nonprod-service-role"
      ~ id                           = "i-0dbe05f55f05d9a4c" -> (known after apply)
      ~ instance_state               = "running" -> (known after apply)
        instance_type                = "r5.4xlarge"
      ~ ipv6_address_count           = 0 -> (known after apply)
      ~ ipv6_addresses               = [] -> (known after apply)
        key_name                     = "mit-surv-nonprod-london"
        monitoring                   = false
      + outpost_arn                  = (known after apply)
      + password_data                = (known after apply)
      + placement_group              = (known after apply)
      ~ primary_network_interface_id = "eni-061ea31bfbb5e93f6" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_dns                  = "ip-10-142-175-43.eu-west-2.compute.internal" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_ip                   = "10.142.175.43" -> (known after apply)
      + public_dns                   = (known after apply)
      + public_ip                    = (known after apply)
      ~ secondary_private_ips        = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ security_groups              = [] -> (known after apply)
        source_dest_check            = true
        subnet_id                    = "subnet-0fc6bd95884e9796a"
      ~ tags                         = {
            "AWSResoureceType"              = "EC2"
            "Account"                       = "MITSURV"
            "ApplicationID"                 = "APP-00682"
            "ApplicationName"               = "MITCAPMARKET"
            "Automation"                    = "PLACEHOLDER"
          ~ "BaseImageName"                 = "redhat_linux_cis_7.X__62__1604538021" -> "Add_Your_Base_AMI_Name"
            "BusinessEntitiy"               = "MIT"
            "CostCentre"                    = "CC55219"
            "DBVersion"                     = "N/A"
            "DataClassification"            = "3"
            "Division"                      = "DEVOPS"
            "Environment"                   = "NONPROD"
            "Name"                          = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EC2"
            "OSVersion"                     = "N/A"
            "Project"                       = "SURV"
            "ProjectCode"                   = "25127-100"
            "Purpose"                       = "QA1"
            "RelVersion"                    = "4.0.0.0.i2"
            "ResourceName"                  = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EC2"
            "VersionNumber"                 = "N/A"
            "Workload"                      = "TEST"
          - "mitcct_ec2_ami-id"             = "ami-0e6de0d71c64a2b5b" -> null
          - "mitcct_ec2_instance-id"        = "i-0dbe05f55f05d9a4c" -> null
          - "mitcct_ec2_instance-type"      = "r5.4xlarge" -> null
          - "mitcct_ec2_local-hostname"     = "ip-10-142-175-43.946581213364.ew2.aws.dev.r53." -> null
          - "mitcct_ec2_local-ipv4"         = "10.142.175.43" -> null
          - "mitcct_ec2_subnet-id"          = "subnet-0fc6bd95884e9796a" -> null
          - "mitcct_ec2_vpc-id"             = "vpc-0b7dd5e37cb613bfa" -> null
          - "mitcct_iam_InstanceProfileArn" = "arn:aws:iam::946581213364:instance-profile/mit-surv-nonprod-service-role" -> null
          - "mitcct_iam_role"               = "mit-surv-nonprod-service-role" -> null
            "node_type"                     = "master"
        }
        tenancy                      = "default"
        user_data                    = "cbca7c32e2ea4dbc3ae3777d3738ca8cbc7218b3"
        vpc_security_group_ids       = [
            "sg-00298692f55f253e5",
        ]

        credit_specification {}

      - ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          - delete_on_termination = true -> null
          - device_name           = "/dev/sdb" -> null
          - encrypted             = true -> null
          - iops                  = 300 -> null
          - kms_key_id            = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:946581213364:key/15dc10ff-885a-4217-ad60-05ef9682d34d" -> null
          - snapshot_id           = "snap-0afd755a1f452c2fe" -> null
          - tags                  = {
              - "AWSResoureceType"   = "EC2"
              - "Account"            = "MITSURV"
              - "ApplicationID"      = "APP-00682"
              - "ApplicationName"    = "MITCAPMARKET"
              - "Automation"         = "PLACEHOLDER"
              - "BaseImageName"      = "Add_Your_Base_AMI_Name"
              - "BusinessEntitiy"    = "MIT"
              - "CostCentre"         = "CC55219"
              - "DBVersion"          = "N/A"
              - "DataClassification" = "3"
              - "Division"           = "DEVOPS"
              - "Environment"        = "NONPROD"
              - "Name"               = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              - "OSVersion"          = "N/A"
              - "Project"            = "SURV"
              - "ProjectCode"        = "25127-100"
              - "Purpose"            = "QA1"
              - "RelVersion"         = "4.0.0.0.i2"
              - "ResourceName"       = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              - "VersionNumber"      = "N/A"
              - "Workload"           = "TEST"
              - "mount"              = "/x01"
              - "node_type"          = "master"
            } -> null
          - throughput            = 0 -> null
          - volume_id             = "vol-036859ecaf1def640" -> null
          - volume_size           = 100 -> null
          - volume_type           = "gp2" -> null
        }
      + ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          + delete_on_termination = true
          + device_name           = "/dev/sdb"
          + encrypted             = true
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:946581213364:key/15dc10ff-885a-4217-ad60-05ef9682d34d"
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + tags                  = {
              + "AWSResoureceType"   = "EC2"
              + "Account"            = "MITSURV"
              + "ApplicationID"      = "APP-00682"
              + "ApplicationName"    = "MITCAPMARKET"
              + "Automation"         = "PLACEHOLDER"
              + "BaseImageName"      = "Add_Your_Base_AMI_Name"
              + "BusinessEntitiy"    = "MIT"
              + "CostCentre"         = "CC55219"
              + "DBVersion"          = "N/A"
              + "DataClassification" = "3"
              + "Division"           = "DEVOPS"
              + "Environment"        = "NONPROD"
              + "Name"               = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              + "OSVersion"          = "N/A"
              + "Project"            = "SURV"
              + "ProjectCode"        = "25127-100"
              + "Purpose"            = "QA1"
              + "RelVersion"         = "4.0.0.0.i2"
              + "ResourceName"       = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              + "VersionNumber"      = "N/A"
              + "Workload"           = "TEST"
              + "mount"              = "/x01"
              + "node_type"          = "master"
            }
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = 100
          + volume_type           = "gp2"
        }
      - ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          - delete_on_termination = true -> null
          - device_name           = "/dev/sdc" -> null
          - encrypted             = true -> null
          - iops                  = 1500 -> null
          - kms_key_id            = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:946581213364:key/15dc10ff-885a-4217-ad60-05ef9682d34d" -> null
          - tags                  = {
              - "AWSResoureceType"   = "EC2"
              - "Account"            = "MITSURV"
              - "ApplicationID"      = "APP-00682"
              - "ApplicationName"    = "MITCAPMARKET"
              - "Automation"         = "PLACEHOLDER"
              - "BaseImageName"      = "Add_Your_Base_AMI_Name"
              - "BusinessEntitiy"    = "MIT"
              - "CostCentre"         = "CC55219"
              - "DBVersion"          = "N/A"
              - "DataClassification" = "3"
              - "Division"           = "DEVOPS"
              - "Environment"        = "NONPROD"
              - "Name"               = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              - "OSVersion"          = "N/A"
              - "Project"            = "SURV"
              - "ProjectCode"        = "25127-100"
              - "Purpose"            = "QA1"
              - "RelVersion"         = "4.0.0.0.i2"
              - "ResourceName"       = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              - "VersionNumber"      = "N/A"
              - "Workload"           = "TEST"
              - "mount"              = "/x02"
              - "node_type"          = "master"
            } -> null
          - throughput            = 0 -> null
          - volume_id             = "vol-0a085bfad9f6cce82" -> null
          - volume_size           = 500 -> null
          - volume_type           = "gp2" -> null
        }
      + ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          + delete_on_termination = true
          + device_name           = "/dev/sdc"
          + encrypted             = true
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:946581213364:key/15dc10ff-885a-4217-ad60-05ef9682d34d"
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + tags                  = {
              + "AWSResoureceType"   = "EC2"
              + "Account"            = "MITSURV"
              + "ApplicationID"      = "APP-00682"
              + "ApplicationName"    = "MITCAPMARKET"
              + "Automation"         = "PLACEHOLDER"
              + "BaseImageName"      = "Add_Your_Base_AMI_Name"
              + "BusinessEntitiy"    = "MIT"
              + "CostCentre"         = "CC55219"
              + "DBVersion"          = "N/A"
              + "DataClassification" = "3"
              + "Division"           = "DEVOPS"
              + "Environment"        = "NONPROD"
              + "Name"               = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              + "OSVersion"          = "N/A"
              + "Project"            = "SURV"
              + "ProjectCode"        = "25127-100"
              + "Purpose"            = "QA1"
              + "RelVersion"         = "4.0.0.0.i2"
              + "ResourceName"       = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              + "VersionNumber"      = "N/A"
              + "Workload"           = "TEST"
              + "mount"              = "/x02"
              + "node_type"          = "master"
            }
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = 500
          + volume_type           = "gp2"
        }
      - ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          - delete_on_termination = true -> null
          - device_name           = "/dev/sdd" -> null
          - encrypted             = true -> null
          - iops                  = 3000 -> null
          - kms_key_id            = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:946581213364:key/15dc10ff-885a-4217-ad60-05ef9682d34d" -> null
          - tags                  = {
              - "AWSResoureceType"   = "EC2"
              - "Account"            = "MITSURV"
              - "ApplicationID"      = "APP-00682"
              - "ApplicationName"    = "MITCAPMARKET"
              - "Automation"         = "PLACEHOLDER"
              - "BaseImageName"      = "Add_Your_Base_AMI_Name"
              - "BusinessEntitiy"    = "MIT"
              - "CostCentre"         = "CC55219"
              - "DBVersion"          = "N/A"
              - "DataClassification" = "3"
              - "Division"           = "DEVOPS"
              - "Environment"        = "NONPROD"
              - "Name"               = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              - "OSVersion"          = "N/A"
              - "Project"            = "SURV"
              - "ProjectCode"        = "25127-100"
              - "Purpose"            = "QA1"
              - "RelVersion"         = "4.0.0.0.i2"
              - "ResourceName"       = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              - "VersionNumber"      = "N/A"
              - "Workload"           = "TEST"
              - "mount"              = "/x03"
              - "node_type"          = "master"
            } -> null
          - throughput            = 0 -> null
          - volume_id             = "vol-07212e8813372626d" -> null
          - volume_size           = 1000 -> null
          - volume_type           = "gp2" -> null
        }
      + ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          + delete_on_termination = true
          + device_name           = "/dev/sdd"
          + encrypted             = true
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:946581213364:key/15dc10ff-885a-4217-ad60-05ef9682d34d"
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + tags                  = {
              + "AWSResoureceType"   = "EC2"
              + "Account"            = "MITSURV"
              + "ApplicationID"      = "APP-00682"
              + "ApplicationName"    = "MITCAPMARKET"
              + "Automation"         = "PLACEHOLDER"
              + "BaseImageName"      = "Add_Your_Base_AMI_Name"
              + "BusinessEntitiy"    = "MIT"
              + "CostCentre"         = "CC55219"
              + "DBVersion"          = "N/A"
              + "DataClassification" = "3"
              + "Division"           = "DEVOPS"
              + "Environment"        = "NONPROD"
              + "Name"               = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              + "OSVersion"          = "N/A"
              + "Project"            = "SURV"
              + "ProjectCode"        = "25127-100"
              + "Purpose"            = "QA1"
              + "RelVersion"         = "4.0.0.0.i2"
              + "ResourceName"       = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              + "VersionNumber"      = "N/A"
              + "Workload"           = "TEST"
              + "mount"              = "/x03"
              + "node_type"          = "master"
            }
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = 1000
          + volume_type           = "gp2"
        }
      - ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          - delete_on_termination = true -> null
          - device_name           = "/dev/sde" -> null
          - encrypted             = true -> null
          - iops                  = 15000 -> null
          - kms_key_id            = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:946581213364:key/15dc10ff-885a-4217-ad60-05ef9682d34d" -> null
          - tags                  = {
              - "AWSResoureceType"   = "EC2"
              - "Account"            = "MITSURV"
              - "ApplicationID"      = "APP-00682"
              - "ApplicationName"    = "MITCAPMARKET"
              - "Automation"         = "PLACEHOLDER"
              - "BaseImageName"      = "Add_Your_Base_AMI_Name"
              - "BusinessEntitiy"    = "MIT"
              - "CostCentre"         = "CC55219"
              - "DBVersion"          = "N/A"
              - "DataClassification" = "3"
              - "Division"           = "DEVOPS"
              - "Environment"        = "NONPROD"
              - "Name"               = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              - "OSVersion"          = "N/A"
              - "Project"            = "SURV"
              - "ProjectCode"        = "25127-100"
              - "Purpose"            = "QA1"
              - "RelVersion"         = "4.0.0.0.i2"
              - "ResourceName"       = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              - "VersionNumber"      = "N/A"
              - "Workload"           = "TEST"
              - "mount"              = "/x04"
              - "node_type"          = "master"
            } -> null
          - throughput            = 0 -> null
          - volume_id             = "vol-0617a2d3ef4eab421" -> null
          - volume_size           = 5000 -> null
          - volume_type           = "gp2" -> null
        }
      + ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
          + delete_on_termination = true
          + device_name           = "/dev/sde"
          + encrypted             = true
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:946581213364:key/15dc10ff-885a-4217-ad60-05ef9682d34d"
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + tags                  = {
              + "AWSResoureceType"   = "EC2"
              + "Account"            = "MITSURV"
              + "ApplicationID"      = "APP-00682"
              + "ApplicationName"    = "MITCAPMARKET"
              + "Automation"         = "PLACEHOLDER"
              + "BaseImageName"      = "Add_Your_Base_AMI_Name"
              + "BusinessEntitiy"    = "MIT"
              + "CostCentre"         = "CC55219"
              + "DBVersion"          = "N/A"
              + "DataClassification" = "3"
              + "Division"           = "DEVOPS"
              + "Environment"        = "NONPROD"
              + "Name"               = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              + "OSVersion"          = "N/A"
              + "Project"            = "SURV"
              + "ProjectCode"        = "25127-100"
              + "Purpose"            = "QA1"
              + "RelVersion"         = "4.0.0.0.i2"
              + "ResourceName"       = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
              + "VersionNumber"      = "N/A"
              + "Workload"           = "TEST"
              + "mount"              = "/x04"
              + "node_type"          = "master"
            }
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = 5000
          + volume_type           = "gp2"
        }

      ~ enclave_options {
          ~ enabled = false -> (known after apply)
        }

      + ephemeral_block_device {
          + device_name  = (known after apply)
          + no_device    = (known after apply)
          + virtual_name = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ metadata_options {
          ~ http_endpoint               = "enabled" -> (known after apply)
          ~ http_put_response_hop_limit = 1 -> (known after apply)
          ~ http_tokens                 = "optional" -> (known after apply)
        }

      + network_interface {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_index          = (known after apply)
          + network_interface_id  = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ root_block_device {
            delete_on_termination = true
          ~ device_name           = "/dev/sda1" -> (known after apply)
            encrypted             = true
          ~ iops                  = 750 -> (known after apply)
            kms_key_id            = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-2:946581213364:key/15dc10ff-885a-4217-ad60-05ef9682d34d"
            tags                  = {
                "AWSResoureceType"   = "EC2"
                "Account"            = "MITSURV"
                "ApplicationID"      = "APP-00682"
                "ApplicationName"    = "MITCAPMARKET"
                "Automation"         = "PLACEHOLDER"
                "BaseImageName"      = "Add_Your_Base_AMI_Name"
                "BusinessEntitiy"    = "MIT"
                "CostCentre"         = "CC55219"
                "DBVersion"          = "N/A"
                "DataClassification" = "3"
                "Division"           = "DEVOPS"
                "Environment"        = "NONPROD"
                "Name"               = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
                "OSVersion"          = "N/A"
                "Project"            = "SURV"
                "ProjectCode"        = "25127-100"
                "Purpose"            = "QA1"
                "RelVersion"         = "4.0.0.0.i2"
                "ResourceName"       = "MITSURV-NONPROD-MITCAPMARKET-SURV-DEVOPS-QA1-MN-1-EBS"
                "VersionNumber"      = "N/A"
                "Workload"           = "TEST"
                "node_type"          = "master"
            }
          ~ throughput            = 0 -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_id             = "vol-042ac0ffd687aec19" -> (known after apply)
            volume_size           = 250
            volume_type           = "gp2"
        }
    }
```

Appreciate your support to understand this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer in [github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8480) and issue resolved with that, Hope this is the correct way of doing this.

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [ebs_block_device,user_data]
}
```